# How to register the Game Center application on iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, iphone-sdk-4.1, ios4

I am working on an application that uses the Game Center feature from iOS 4.1.

While studying Game Center I got to know that it uses Game Center service to post leaderBoard and achievements. I have already a registered user of Game Center but don't know how to register my application to iTunesConnect as I need to post my scores and achievements on Game Center.

How can I register my application on iTunes connect and also for Setting the achievements and leaderBoard facilities with it?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doc should have what you need: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think this link provides the information you're looking for: [Game Center Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

The general gist of it is to create a new app in your account (making sure to match the Bundle ID to your app), then under Features, you can select Game Center. This allows you to manage your Leaderboards and Achievements.

Then, upload a build. On the main 'Prepare for Submission' page for this build, use the toggle to enable Game Center, and select specific Leaderboards and Achievements that should be available to that version.